# Missing bower packages Ember.js 1.11.1 when deploying on Heroku

Tags: heroku, ember.js, ember-cli

I've got a problem when I want to deploy an ember-cli app in Heroku.

This is what it's returned to me :

```
Missing bower packages: 
Package: ember
  * Specified: 1.11.1
  * Installed: 1.11.0

Run `bower install` to install missing dependencies.
```

On my computer, in localhost, it works fine when I do `ember serve` in the terminal. `ember build` works too.

The problem occured when I wanted to update from ember 1.11.0 to 1.11.1.
I wanted to go back and use the previous version of ember (1.11.0) but the problem remains.

Someone has an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I clean up the cache by installing the Heroku Repo plugin.

```
$ heroku plugins:install https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo.git
$ heroku repo:purge_cache -a appname
```